# C# Function failing to update ASP textbox total

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of functions multiplying the input of a quantity value to get the total for 3 separate corresponding textboxes.  That is working just fine.

Now I am trying to include a function that will show the total sum of these 3 separated values into a separate textbox, "tbCombinedTotals".  This is an ASP.net web application, I believe all the markup is correct, but currently when I include the new "CostEstimation" function I created, it does not work.  Here is my C# back-end code:

```
    protected void TextBox1_checkedchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    decimal Cost = 2.50m;
    decimal TextBox1Total = decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * Cost;
    tbTextBoxTotal1.Text = TextBox1Total.ToString();
    CostEstimation();
    }
    //there are 2 more of these for TextBox2_CheckChanged and TextBox3_CheckChanged

    protected void CostEstimation()
    {
        decimal Temp = decimal.Parse(tbTextBoxTotal1.Text);
        decimal Temp2 = decimal.Parse(tbTextBoxTotal2.Text);
        decimal Temp3 = decimal.Parse(tbTextBoxTotal3.Text);
        decimal Temp4 = Temp + Temp2 + Temp3;
        tbCombinedTotals.Text = Temp4.ToString();
    //this should update the "tbCombinedTotals" textbox with the sum of the other 3
    }
```

The first part is working, the tbTextBoxTotal 1-3 textboxes update correctly, but when I include the "CostEstimation()" line, that stops working, and the tbCombinedTotals textbox does not update at all.

I'm sure I am missing something simple, any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks to Steven and the Debugger I was able to get it SORT OF working, changed it to this:

```
    protected void CostEstimation()
    {
        decimal Temp = 0;
        decimal Temp2 = 0;
        decimal Temp3 = 0;
        decimal Temp4 = 0;
        try
        {
            Temp = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", tbTextBoxTotal1.Text));
            Temp2 = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", tbTextBoxTotal2.Text));
            Temp3 = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", tbTextBoxtotal3.Text));
            Temp4 = Temp + Temp2 + Temp3;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        tbCombinedTotals.Text = Temp4.ToString();
    }
```

However, now my only (I think) remaining problem is that the tbCombinedTotals box only updates when all 3 box's are filled out.

I think this is due to the try statement not working until all textboxes have a value...

Comment: I have the CostEstimation function at the end of all 3 CheckChanged functions, because I want the combined total box to update everytime there is a change to any of the input values.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with _stops working_ TextBox remains empty? Error messages?

Comment: When you debug, what specifically happens?  As you step through each line in the debugger, does each variable contain what you expect it to?  Is anything else also writing values to these text boxes?

Comment: No error, no crash, just the 3 quantity total boxes remain blank, and the combined total box remains blank.  Running in debug with a breakpoint, will report back further details.

Is there anything wrong with just calling "CostEstimation" Like I am doing?  Also there is a ; in the actual code though the above is missing one on that line.

Comment: Did you set these textboxes to blank in your Page_Load event? If yes, did you check for IsPostback before setting them to blank?

Comment: *"Also there is a ; in the actual code"* - Which begs the question... What other differences exist between the code you're showing us and "the actual code"?

Comment: Hmm, I put a breakpoint at "tbCombinedtotals.Text = Temp4.ToString();" and it never reached there.  Running again with the breakpoint at "CostEstimation()" and checking variables.

Comment: @David only the names have been changed for confidentiality and readability.

Comment: Ran the debugger.  I'm getting System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: @Steve, no I did not set these textboxes to blank in the Page_Load event.  Yes, I did set AutoPostBack="True" in markup.

Comment: Probably one of your textboxes is empty. Parse cannot handle an empty string. Use Int32.TryParse.

Comment: @Steve you were correct.

Comment: Well not fully. It should be decimal.TryParse, but, yes the reason is the same. Parse raises exception if the string is not convertible. TryParse let you handle the situation in a safer way.

Comment: It is not the "try" that doesn't work, but the Convert.ToDecimal that gives an exception when the text isn't convertible to a decimal (because it is empty)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is now, the total cost ONLY fills out once the 3 textboxtotal1-3 have been filled out by the inputs from textbox1-3. I tried setting "text="0"" on these 3 boxes so that they have a default value, but that does not seem to work for some reason.

Comment: I'm sure I'll figure out and post the solution soon.  Thx for the help, Steve and Hans

Comment: Please see the solution below.  Still not sure why the markup (Text="0") isn't actually working but my issue was trying to add textboxes with empty strings.   Thx for the help.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting down voted on this post, feel free to comment if you have insight as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, despite adding " text="0" " in the markup, I was still having an issue where the total was only calculated after a value was entered in each of the 3 quantity boxes.  I modified the function to check if the checkbox contains an empty string, and set it to 0 if it is:

```
    protected void CostEstimation()
    {
        decimal Temp = 0;
        decimal Temp2 = 0;
        decimal Temp3 = 0;
        decimal Temp4 = 0;
        if (tbTextBoxTotal1.Text == "")
        {
            tbTextBoxTotal1.Text = "0";
        }
        if (tbTextBoxTotal2.Text == "")
        {
            tbTextBoxTotal2.Text = "0";
        }
        if (tbTextBoxTotal3.Text == "")
        {
            tbTextBoxTotal3.Text = "0";
        }
        try
        {
            Temp = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", tbTextBoxTotal1.Text));
            Temp2 = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", tbTextBoxTotal2.Text));
            Temp3 = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", ttbTextBoxTotal3.Text));
            Temp4 = Temp + Temp2 + Temp3;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        tbCombinedTotals.Text = Temp4.ToString();
    }
```

Now as a bonus I'll try to figure out why adding " Text="0" " doesn't actually seem to set the textbox's value to 0 in the markup, since clearly my added if statements show that the issue was the strings in the textboxes being empty.